# silverlight storyboard animation with rotatetransform code behind

Tags: silverlight, animation, rotation, code-behind, storyboard

i am trying to rotate an object from code behind. Code below:

```
        Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();

        //Transform
        RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform();
        rotate.Angle = 45;
        rotate.CenterX = 50;
        rotate.CenterY = 20;
        RodBorder.RenderTransform = rotate;

        DoubleAnimation Anim = new DoubleAnimation();
        Anim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));
        Anim.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, rotate);


        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Anim, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Angle"));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(Anim, RodBorder);

        storyBoard.Children.Add(Anim);
        storyBoard.Begin();
```

RodBorder is a Border which i want to rotate. The problem here is probably the PropertyPath, because i got an exception there.(System.Windows.PropertyPath cannot be set to type System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform) Any ideas are welcome, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Rotation)"`.

You can always verify syntax by building sample animation in Blend.